# Want to Look at Examples that Came With Flex 3 SDK 3.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I just updated my Flex Builder 3 SDK to 3.6. I want to take a look at the samples that came with it. It has the following instructions:

> Continue by reviewing the explorer
>   sample. To run the explorer sample,
>   you must first compile it running the
>   install_root/samples/explorer/build.bat
>   (Windows) or
>   install_root/samples/explorer/build.sh
>   (UNIX and Mac OS X) files. For more
>   information on the Flex compilers, see
>   the "Using the Flex Compilers" chapter
>   in the Building and Deploying Flex
>   Applications manual.

I'm on a Mac. I found the build.sh file. But, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with it.

Thank you!

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open `Terminal.app`
2. Type `cd` (do not forget a space after `cd`) and then drag your `install_root/samples/explorer/` folder from `Finder` to Terminal and press `Enter`.
3. Type in Terminal `./build.sh` and press Enter.

I suppose these steps should work.

Comment: Hi Constantiner, Thank you for the excellent directions. I followed them and it was comiled. Now I have to figure out how to import them into Flex Builder 3.